# Как получить индексы строк в DataFrame с заданными значениями start и end?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

У меня есть файл, который я загружаю в DataFrame. В одной из колонок находится список дат в формате: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` (например `2012.01.01 00:00`) с интервалом в 30 минут.

У меня есть две даты (из тех, которые точно есть в этом DataFrame). Мне нужно выполнять определенные действия с теми данными, которые входят в промежуток от одной (начальной) даты до второй (конечной).

Например, я ввожу:

```
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012.05.07 00:00', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012.07.12 23:30', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
```

Нужно получить индексы строк, в которых находятся эти даты, чтобы потом обрабатывать данные, которые входят в интервал от `start` до `end`.

[Ссылка на файл с данными](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmVEImbxNmoUtqgS7yF9et_IZq8tnKp0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: приведите хотя бы часть данных для воспроизводимого примера. поиск по значению в датафрейме достаточно тривиален, но зависит от того, каковы ваши данные.

Comment: сам поиск будет производиться по дате в таком формате ('2012-01-01 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'). То есть имея переменную с datetime вот такого формата нужно найти строку в dataframe с таким же значением

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU отредактировал вопрос, добавил свой файл с данными и (как мне кажется) более понятно обьяснил суть вопроса.

Comment: @strawdog отредактировал вопрос, добавил свой файл с данными и (как мне кажется) более понятно обьяснил суть вопроса

Comment: @TedMosby, вы хотите получить индексы строк с датами находящимися между `start` и `end` или строки с датами которые равны `start` и `end`?

Comment: @MaxU ну, если я буду иметь индексы строк, которые равны `start` и `end`, то получить те, которые между ними не составит труда.

Comment: @TedMosby, сравните время реакции на вопрос с примером данных и без - `7 мин` vs. `19 часов` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала читаем данные и параллельно парсим даты:

```
In [40]: df = pd.read_excel(filename, parse_dates=["date"], index_col=0)
```

Парсить даты можно и после прочтения:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce")
```

получим:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
                    date    T        dd  FF
0    2012-01-01 00:00:00  0.0       NaN   0
1    2012-01-01 00:30:00  0.0       NaN   0
2    2012-01-01 01:00:00  0.0       NaN   0
3    2012-01-01 01:30:00  0.0       С-З   1
4    2012-01-01 02:00:00  0.0       NaN   0
...                  ...  ...       ...  ..
1483 2012-12-31 21:30:00 -4.0  Западный   2
1484 2012-12-31 22:00:00 -5.0  Западный   3
1485 2012-12-31 22:30:00 -5.0  Западный   3
1486 2012-12-31 23:00:00 -5.0  Западный   4
1487 2012-12-31 23:30:00 -5.0  Западный   2

[17568 rows x 4 columns]
```

ищем индексы строк попадающих в интервал дат:

```
In [42]: idx = df.query("@start < date < @end").index
```

результат:

```
In [43]: idx
Out[43]:
Int64Index([289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298,
            ...
            565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574],
           dtype='int64', length=3214)
```

Если нужны строки, а не соответствующие индексы:

```
In [44]: df.query("@start < date < @end")
Out[44]:
                   date     T          dd  FF
289 2012-05-07 00:30:00  15.0  Переменный   2
290 2012-05-07 01:00:00  15.0         NaN   0
291 2012-05-07 01:30:00  15.0         NaN   0
292 2012-05-07 02:00:00  16.0         С-З   3
293 2012-05-07 02:30:00  16.0    Северный   4
..                  ...   ...         ...  ..
570 2012-07-12 21:00:00  23.0         NaN   0
571 2012-07-12 21:30:00  23.0         NaN   0
572 2012-07-12 22:00:00  23.0         NaN   0
573 2012-07-12 22:30:00  22.0         NaN   0
574 2012-07-12 23:00:00  22.0         NaN   0

[3214 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: а зачем мы параллельно парсим даты в самом начале?

Comment: @TedMosby, можно сделать это и непараллельно - это не принципиально, а после чтения Excel - главное получить столбец с типом данных `datetime64`, а не `object`

Comment: а как парсить после прочтения файла?

Comment: @TedMosby, дополнил ответ...

Comment: И последний вопрос, если потребуется получить отдельно индексы `start` и `end`, как это делать?

Comment: @TedMosby, `df.query("date in [@start, @end]").index`

Comment: спасибо большое)